# Can fermions composing a boson ignore Pauli's principle?

Tags: fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, bosons

After a discussion with a fellow student, we came above this problem asked as question in the title.

A similar question was answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45644/can-bosons-that-are-composed-of-several-fermions-occupy-the-same-state).
But it doesn't answer the question for us.

In a BEC, many, many bosons composed of fermions share the same wave function. So the argument about spatial delocalization doesn't apply. (Or does it?)

The questions:
  1. Can the fermions actually ignore Pauli's principle?
 2a. If yes, how can this be explained?
 2b. If not, how can the condensate be explained?
 3. How can bosons composed of fermions with different quantum states have the same quantum state? (Also in regard to cooper pairs.)

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that "fermions share the same wave function". Just because the bosonic state was formed by two fermionic states ingoing, you *cannot* expect that there is a meaningful way to assign states to the individual fermions "inside" the boson. So how do you want to apply Pauli's principle here?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266392/why-the-cooper-pair-do-not-obey-the-exclusion-principle#

Comment: Take a look at Ben Crowell's answer to this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/huge-confusion-with-fermions-and-bosons-and-how-they-relate-to-total-spin-of-ato/66734#66734